# Failed to install flutter absolute path

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Add the dependency of flutter absolute path in my flutter project but when compiling my application it shows me the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ezG0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio -> File -> Open -> yourFlutterProject -> android -> open

and build.gradle / app change minSdkVersion to 19

and Builde -> rebuild Project

[image]